# What file formats, file sizes, and frame rates are supported for animated ads managed by DFP?

Tags: advertising, google-dfp

What are the most standard specifications for an animated ad in terms of file format, file size, frames per second and etc.?

I am preparing a media kit for our advertisers and can't seem to find a consistent answer on this. So far I found the following:

> File Type: .SWF, .GIF, .FLA
>
> File Size: 60k to 100k
>
> Frames per Second: no more then 24 frames
>
> Durations: 12 - 30 seconds
>
> *All ads should be coded so that click-thrus launch a new browser window using target="_blank".

Ads will be managed with Google DFP.